# How to execute vscode extension `git.push` command with no verify parameter?

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I try to create vs code extension, that will be add action button to make git push command with `--no-verify` parameter to ignore run pre-push hook.

I tried this:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('git.push', ["--no-verify"]).then(() => {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Changes pushed without verification!');
});
```

But it does't work.

Comment: I suggest you check out the actual source code and see whether Microsoft designs it to allow custom arguments to be passed, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/git/src/commands.ts#L2174

Comment: @LexLi Is there any way to override this command by allowing it to accept additional parameters?